# Can't choose home router

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection, adsl

I have no fear of console and my old routers are awful (DSL-500T for bridging ADSL to LAN and then DSL-524 for distributing LAN across network and provide Wi-Fi). So I've decided to replace it with some newer stuff. The features I need:

- Gigabit ethernet ports (at least 2)
- ADSL
- 802.11n
- QoS
- VPN (preferably)

I've searched some manufacturers (Linksys, Asus, Netgear, Cisco) and didn't find anything, that satisfies my requirements. So, if you can, please, recommend me some hardware and if this not possible, hardware combinations (such as router + ADSL modem).

Answer (score 0):

"I am not dummy"

After reading the first 4 words of your question I have decided that since you're "not dummy" you should buy a "Fisher-Price My First ADSL2+ Modem/Router"

On a more serious note, these are all fantastic modem/routers that don't quite meet your specifications, but you may want to look sidewise in the product line to see if there is that perfect router you are searching for:

- Dynalink RTA-1025W (10/100, no VPN, no 802.11n)
- Cisco 877W (Gigabit, no 802.11n)
- Zyxel P-662HW-D (10/100, no 802.11n)

EDIT: You obviously didn't search Cisco very hard, I typed "cisco wireless n router" into Google and look what came up!

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9931/

Chuck in a modem and you'll be good to go!

[image]

EDIT2: The Cisco 867W offers 4x 10/100 ports with optional wireless n: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9562/index.html

Comment: 802.11n and Gigabit ports is a must. The speed of 802.11g/100 Mbit just isn't enough to work with video wirelessly (across the local network, of course). I have found that Cisco and this Linksys (http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/WRT610N) and even AirPort Extreme suits my needs fully, except the ADSL part. It's not hard to buy ADSL-modem, but it would be much better if it was built-in.

Answer (score 0):

D-Link DIR 825 or 855 + ADSL modem and you have all you've requested + some neat features like dual wireless bands, dynamic DNS support, UPnP support and a printer server.

Comment: where did you see the VPN support?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible to have all these features on a combined modem/router... So I will recommend that you keep your DSL-500T as a ADSL modem only (or buy a not too expensive one)  and add it a [DD-WRT compatible router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) (You could also check [this list](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) to have more hardware infos). It's an open source firmware with a linux kernel so you could have professional features like VPN, QoS and [many others](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_%22DD-WRT%22%3F) on your home router. ([OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start) and [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) are popular choice too)

The Linksys [WRT610N (v2)](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/WRT610N) would be my choice (compared to the 320N more for the processor & memory spec than the usb port...)

Additionaly this [smallnetbuilder.com page](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/component/option,com_chart/Itemid,189/) should interest you

Comment: That's probably the best solution. Linksys is higher quality than some other brands, it's fast and dd-wrt is sooo cool. Thank you for recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

[**BiPAC 7402NX**](http://www.billionsa.com/product/3g/bipac7402nx-wireless-11n-3G-ADSL2-vpn-firewall-router.html)

[image]

> - Compliant with ADSL Standard
> - 4-port Gigabit Switch
> - Secured VPN with powerful DES/3DES/AES
> - Quality of Service (QoS)
> - Compliant with IEEE 802.11n draft, 802.11g, 802.11b and standards